# Underscore and LoDash _.each

Tags: javascript, migration, underscore.js, lodash

I'm in the process of migrating a code base from Underscore 1.8.2 to lodash 4.5.1. There was one test that failed after the migration.

The code being tested was a recursive summation using `_.each`.

```
function foo(elements) {
  if (elements.isContainer()) {
    var sum = 0;
    _.each(elements, function(element) {
      sum += foo(element);
    });
    return sum;
  } else {
    return elements.someAttr ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Testing with an array that should be empty, `0` is expected as the result. `underscore.each` succeeded, but lodash did not (a positive value was returned).

I replaced the `_.each(...` with `return _.sumBy(...`, and the tests passed, but I am concerned that there may be more dormant issues within the code base.

**Any ideas as to which difference between the two libraries would cause this?**

Comment: what is `elements` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was actually in the test code. Above, `elements` was an array at runtime, but is the result of dereferencing a Knockout observable array. The spy created for the test was providing an observable instead of an array.

The difference between underscore and lodash here is that lodash uses `Array.isArray` to determine the type of the object passed. Underscore on the other hand just checks for the existence of the `length` property, which exists on Functions.

Underscore was treating the function as an Object, lodash was treating it as an Array.